# VSCode equivalent of WebStorm's "Update Project"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm recently moving from WebStorm to VSCode and missing this "**Update Project**" (`⌘T`) feature (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#update). Basically what it does is `git fetch --all` and then `git merge` for each local branch (like `git pull -all` but also `git merge` for each other local branch in addition to the current local branch). Is there such a VSCode equivalent of this?

Comment: I'm not aware of a vscode equivalent, but it would be very easy to configure a custom vscode task to run a few bash commands.

Comment: You're right. I believe that's the closest I can get. I'll answer my own question based on this. Thanks for the pointer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@CollinD's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77770295/vscode-equivalent-of-webstorms-update-project/77770317#comment137106533_77770295), I ended up creating a custom user's task (wrapping [`hub sync`](https://hub.github.com/hub-sync.1.html)) and the corresponding keybinding for it:

**tasks.json**

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Update Project",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "hub sync",
      "presentation": {
        "clear": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**keybindings.json**

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
  {
    "key": "cmd+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Update Project"
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+t",
    "command": "-workbench.action.showAllSymbols"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+cmd+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.showAllSymbols"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the Git tab, you can sync changes with the remote branch. I don't believe it's exactly like the "Update Project" in JetBrains, but it's very similar. You can also install the GitLens extension (highly suggested) to improve the Git integration in VSCode. Here's a [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview) that gives you an intro to Git in VSCode.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but sorry, I tried GitLens earlier; I think it's too bloated and I just don't wanna do any "funny business" with the paid version of GitKraken ‍♂️